# Folder within another folder no longer in alphabetical order

Tags: docusaurus

I am trying to figure out why a folder I created underneath another folder is no longer in alphabetical order

Here is the layout that I want

```
Environment
  Overview
  A topic that starts with A
  A topic that starts with C
  A topic that starts with J
  My new folder which starts with K
     K doc 1
     K doc 2
```

What I get is the K folder right after the Overview. I read about the `_category_.json` file so I create one at the environment level

```
{
  "label": "Environment",
  "position": 1
}
```

In the K folder I created another `_category_.json`. I used the following:

```
  "label": "Kibana",
  "position": 2
}
```

If I remove the position, Kibana goes go the bottom of the list. I have tried entering a position of 6 because of other files but it goes to the second position after the overview.

Answer (score 0):

Just number your files, using a dash `-` to separate from the filename.

Docusaurus will strip out the number, and keep the position and filename.

**Example:**

```
01-a_directory
02-b_directory
03-c_directory
04-d_directory
05-e_directory
06-f_directory
```

---

Also, if you number some of your files and others not, the ones that are not numbered will be displayed after the numbered ones.

Comment: Thanks @D.Kastier. Unfortunately, we we told not to use numbers in our file names.